# asymptotic solution of recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, data-structure

can you help me to solve this recurrence equation asymptotically?

my recurrence relation is
$f\left(n\right)=f\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+f\left(\frac{n}{6}\right)+\left(n\right)^{\sqrt{\log\ n}}$
I tried to solve this recurrence relation with recursive tree but it did not work because of the function that make my relation nonhomogeneous! please help me to solve it!